# Convolution of two distribution functions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, convolution

I have two functions;

```
f[x_] = (1/k) Exp[-x/k] ;
g[x_] = (1/p) Exp[-x/p] ;
```

How I can convolve them?

In Mathematica for convolving two functions we have this function:

```
Convolve[f, g, x, ??]
```

But I don't know how to do the convolution with the above function for my case.

before I ask this question I searched in detail but I didn't find what I need.

Note: the solution of the above functions is:

```
(1/k) Exp[-x/k]  *  (1/p) Exp[-x/p]  =  (1/(k-p)) ( Exp[-x/k]  - Exp[-x/p] )
```

where * is the convolution.

So, how to do this convolution in Mathematica?

Comment: `Convolve[f, g, x, y]` gives zero (y is the convolution dummy variable)

Comment: @Nasser You don't happen to have used the OP definitions of the functions? They are not written with the correct Mathematica syntax. Should have been `f = (1/k) Exp [-x/k];g = (1/p) Exp [-x/p];`

Comment: You need to use proper _Mathematica_ syntax; the exponential function is `Exp[]`. Next issue is that the integral will not converge on `[-Infinity, Infinity]`.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I just copied what OP wrote and did not even notice the exp vs. Exp ;) , oh boy, now I look at it, I see more syntax errors , using "(" vs. "[" . I need to go make some strong coffee

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The functions do not have a finite area, so they cannot be real distributions as your title claims they are.

Let's change them a bit so they have area 1.

```
f[x_] = (1/k) Exp[-x/k] UnitStep[x]; 
g[x_] = (1/p) Exp[-x/p] UnitStep[x]; 

Integrate[f[x], {x, -∞, ∞}]
```

> ConditionalExpression[1, Re[1/k] > 0]

The convolution:

```
Convolve[f[x], g[x], x, y]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

which equals (well apart from the unit step) what you were expecting.

Since your title mentions convolution of distributions let's explore that route as well. A convolution of two probability distributions is defined as the distribution of the sum of two stochastic variables distributed according to those distributions:

```
PDF[
   TransformedDistribution[
      x + y, 
      {
         x \[Distributed] ProbabilityDistribution[f[x], {x, -∞, ∞}], 
         y \[Distributed] ProbabilityDistribution[g[x], {x, -∞, ∞}]
      }
   ],x
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

Well, almost. Better to be a bit more complete.

$$\mathrm{E}\mathrm{D}\mathrm{C}\left(b,\beta; t\right)=\mathrm{b}{e}^{-bt} \otimes \beta {e}^{-\beta t} = \left\{\begin{array}{l}\left.\begin{array}{l}\mathrm{b}\beta \frac{e^{-\beta t}-{e}^{-bt}}{\mathrm{b}-\beta },\ \mathrm{b}\ne \beta \\ {}\kern1.75em {\mathrm{b}}^2t\ {e}^{-\mathrm{b}t}\kern0.5em ,\ \mathrm{b}=\beta \end{array}\right\}t\ge 0\\ {}\left.\kern3.75em 0\kern4.1em \right\}t<0\end{array}\right..$$

From this [link](https://ejnmmiphys.springeropen.com/articles/10.1186/s40658-016-0166-z).

That is, there is a special case and another way to do a convolution for simple cases:

```
 Convolve[PDF[ExponentialDistribution[b],z],PDF[ExponentialDistribution[b],z],z,t]
```

$\begin{array}{cc}
 \Big\{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 b^2 t e^{-b t} & t>0 \\
 0 & \text{True} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}$